# ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long

Tags: windows-10, aes, python-3.5

Пишу програмку для школы. Долблюсь с ошибкой, описанной выше уже минут 20.
Вот код:

```
def aes():
    #aes
    os.system('cls')
    print('1.Шифруем')
    print('2.Дешифруем')

    c = input('Ваш выбор:')

    if int(c) == 1:
        #shifr
        os.system('cls')
        print('Шифруем значит')
        print('Введите текст, который хотите зашифровать')
        text = input()

        f = open('plaintext.txt', 'w')
        f.write(text)
        f.close()

        BLOCK_SIZE = 32
        PADDING = '{'
        pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
        EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
        secret = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)

        f = open('aeskey.txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(secret))
        f.close()

        f = open('plaintext.txt', 'r')
        privateInfo = f.read()
        f.close()

        cipher = AES.new(secret)

        encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, privateInfo)

        f = open('plaintext.txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(encoded))
        f.close()
        print(str(encoded))

    if int(c) == 2:
        os.system('cls')
        print('Дешифруем значит')

        f = open('plaintext.txt','r')
        encryptedString = f.read()
        f.close()

        PADDING = '{'
        DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
        encryption = encryptedString

        f = open('aeskey.txt', 'r')
        key = f.read()
        f.close()

        cipher = AES.new(key)
        decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encryption)

        f = open('plaintext.txt', 'w')
        f.write(decoded)
        f.close()

        print(decoded)
```

Ошибка полностью:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/vital/Desktop/Prog/Python/Enc_dec/Enc_dec.py", line 341, in
>   
>       aes() 
> File "C:/Users/vital/Desktop/Prog/Python/Enc_dec/Enc_dec.py", line 180, in
>   aes
>       cipher = AES.new(key)  
>  File "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py",
>   line 179, in new
>       return AESCipher(key, *args, **kwargs) 
>   File "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py",
>   line 114, in **init**
>       blockalgo.BlockAlgo.**init**(self, _AES, key, *args, **kwargs) 
>   File
>   "C:\Users\vital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py",
>   line 401, in **init**
>       self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs) ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Посчитал, что ключ 32 байта, все равно.

Comment: Какой у вас там ключ?

Comment: secret = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE)

Comment: Проверяйте что у вас из файла читается, нет ли там лишних символов. Попробовал построчно исполнить программу (без чтения/сохранения в файл) - всё работает.